# Multiple images on one page: best ranking practices

Tags: html, search-engines, search-engine-indexing, ranking, image-search

I have several images related to one object and they all should be placed on one web-page. I'd like to know how do I place those images among the page body and its text. I can not do it manually to distribute the images evenly among the page so I'd do the following:

APPROACH ONE: I'd place only one image with its corresponding caption text below, alt and title somewhere in the top of the page with all the rest text following this image. All other images should replace the first one by JS-function as the user pressing the corresponding button "Next".  QUESTION: Will Google (and the rest of search engines) index the images indicated only in JS section of the page? And even if 'yes' will SE's rank them in the same way? I'd bear with it if the first image will be considered as the main and the others as less important.

APPROACH TWO: I'd place all images one after another with attribute 'hidden' for all of them except the first one. The caption will be placed in the end of those images bunch and the alt- ant title-tags will be the same for all of the images. QUESTIONS: I can suppose that the last image will be considered as the most important by the SE's as the caption will be most close to it and I don't really like it.

Please advise me which approach is better or propose yours. The image search is supposed to be the most important source of traffic so it's very important for me.

Comment: After reading this a few times, I'm still unsure what you're trying to achieve. If all the images are on the page and contain an optimised alt tag, file name and relevant surrounding copy context, then they will all rank in image search...

Comment: I'm sorry , @Geoff, that my message is so unclear. Let's try to make it more clear

Q1: If the images mentioned only in JS section will they be indexed by major SE's?

Q2: Is it OK if several images on one page has the similar alt and title tags?

Q3: Images indicated with attribute 'hidden' is indexed and ranked by the SE's the same way as the images with out this attribute?

Comment: Just a quick note. Please note that search engines also use text that renders close to the image to be related and relevant to that specific image. Also please make sure that your images are optimised for web as this reduces image size dramatically. As the second lot of images are hidden or not loaded i think it unlikely that google will index that content in the same way that google sometimes penalizes a webmaster for hidding text or changing it to the same colour of the background

Comment: Yes, @Liam. Your statement is clear. But I see lots of successful sites with JS image manipulations like ones I suggested above.

Comment: @RomanMatveev if you are serving images via javascript to be sure that search engines are able to index these google crawlable ajax and look at the google response to serving a static html version for the googlebot

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't understand you clearly , but tell me are u trying achieve some thing like a Gallery kind of page and u want those images to be displayed when Google image search is done?
Display all images in a small size with a title and and proper `alt` attribute and name.
On click of that image make it popup and enlarge with corresponding details and fade the background.
Hope my answer helps u.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about what images you are going to use, but if we're talking about something in the dimensions of 150x150~250x250 you can, and should use `sprite` for that purpose, Google loves sprites it will speed up your load time, you can optimize it with `tinypng.com` for example, what I am trying to say is that the advantages of sprite images are a lot.

It's not a good practice to use the same `alt` and `title` tags for more than 1 image.

Make sure you optimize the images, by compressing them and setting expire headers for them.